# How to convert 1D2H time scale to Hours

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset where duration is marked as "1D2H" where D = days and H = Hours
I'm trying to convert this in excel so that "1D2H" will =  "26"
I've tried different techniques but have not found a viable solution.

The possible scenarios of this problem are

1D8H,
2D16H,
8H,
4H,

What would be the best way to tackle this problem.

Comment: Hmmm - what have you actually tried? Seems pretty straightforward based on `Find`ing `D` and `H`.

Comment: I've tried removing the H and D and using sub strring methods to multiply but this seems very farfetched for this problem

Comment: `I've tried removing the H and D and using sub strring methods to multiply` Let us take a look at your work

Comment: so you tried: `=LEFT(A1,FIND("D",A1)-1)*24+MID(A1,FIND("D",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND("D",A1)-1)` and it did not work?

Comment: Or something like `=LEFT(A1,FIND("D",A1)-1)*24+MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"H",""),FIND("D",A1)+1,999)`.

Comment: Or this more intricate: `=SUMPRODUCT(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"D","</b><b>D</b><b>"),"H","</b><b>H</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b["&{1,3}&"]"),CHOOSE(MATCH(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"D","</b><b>D</b><b>"),"H","</b><b>H</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b["&{2,4}&"]"),{"D","H"},0),24,1))`

Comment: I have tried neither of these solutions and have also realized my solution is flawed.
This solution work, however if the format shifts to just 18H or anythign below 24 hours the formula fails
=LEFT(A1,FIND("D",A1)-1)*24+MID(A1,FIND("D",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND("D",A1)-1)

Comment: @M.Ustun then you need to show all the possibilities and not just one.  We cannot answer what we do not know.  Please [edit] the question and show an example of all the possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an IF:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("D",A1)),LEFT(A1,FIND("D",A1)-1)*24+IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("D",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND("D",A1)-1),0),--LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you this seems to work however, when the value is set to 1D alone (Which isn't in formula) the Excel throws an error.
I have modified the formula to look like this but it gives me an error.
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("D",D2)),(LEFT(D2,FIND("D",D2)-1)*IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("H",D2)),24+MID(D2,FIND("D",D2)+1,LEN(D2)-FIND("D",D2)-1),1),--LEFT(D2,LEN(D2)-1))

Where am I going wrong

Comment: @M.Ustun that was not an option you provided in your example.

Comment: @M.Ustun see edit, and please the next question, give us all possible inputs, we are not mind readers.

Comment: My apologies, thank you for your time and effort. Why did you use an IFError and not a IF on it's own if you don't mind me asking.

Comment: If there is no `h` then that part will error, it was easier to capture the error at that point.

Answer (score 3):

A shorter formula solution, using SUBSTITUTE function

In `B1` formula copied down :

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"D","/1/1900 "),"H",":00")*24
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome use of date/time.